# Wireshark 2.6.4 dissector No such function/property for object type 'Tvb'

Tags: lua, wireshark

A lua script that works with Wireshark 2.2.4 and Lua 5.2.4 does not work with Wireshark 2.6.4 and Lua 5.2.4.

The error is:

> Lua: Error during loading:
>
> [Path to the script]:[line]: No such 'foo' function/property for object type 'Tvb'

The offending line in the script is the following declaration:

```
function Tvb:foo(param1, param2, param3)
```

Why does this script work with an older version of Wireshark but not the current one?